# Can only see javascript portion of code and not html on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I was building a web page which returns several aspects of a movie from a search form. Essentially you type a movie name and a request is sent to the OMDB API which returns movie details such as title, director, year, poster etc. My biggest problem is that only the Javascript portion of my app appears whilst the html doesn't appear except when the page loads for a millisecond or so and the loading cursor wouldn't go away. Hope someone can give me tips on what went wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:
the form which redirects me to another page:

```
<form action="search_Results.html" method="GET">
  <input type="text" value="Search..." onFocus="this.value='';" onBlur="if 
    (this.value == '') {this.value ='';}" name="search_Input"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Search Results</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>

  <script src = "js\search_Results.js"></script>

</html>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
 var queryString = window.location.search;
 var q_String = queryString.slice(14);
 var final_string = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + q_String + 
"&apikey=3835e1a1";

function apiCall(strings) {
  $.getJSON(strings).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    document.write(response.Year);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(response.Title);
    document.write("<br>");
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = response.Poster;
    img.width = 300;
    img.height = 438;
    img.alt = "N/A";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 

  "url('http://www.51tmp.com/d/file/2015/07/25.jpg')";
  });
 }
 apiCall(final_string);
```

Comment: I see the inclusion of JS in HTML is incorrect. Could you try with the below snippet?

`<script src = "js/search_Results.js"></script>`

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. I might add, instead of my default title, the paremeter name and it's value in the URL become the title, so everything after the '?'

Comment: Rather call the apiCall method on "submit" of the first HTML page which you've mentioned and in the method get the value of the textbox using `document.getElementsByName('search_Input')[0].value` 

Make the button type "submit" to "button"

Comment: `document.write()` will clear your html (which is exactly what is happening).  Try it now: open browser console, enter `document.write("hello");`.   Instead, add a DOM node like you are with the img later and set its text/html and append.

Comment: Thanks heaps, freedomn-m, you just saved me a lot of time and that solves my only problem for the web app! :)